I have a html table where I am showing a sales report. I need to highlight a value in the table if it is present
I want to highlight if there is a Product name "Mango". sometimes the data might be there or may not be there. Is it possible to do so using simple html? As I am embedding this report to outlook mail body.

this is the table generated in email body

unable to add a table picture, my ask is, I need to highlight a value in the table if it exists and this table is embedded to outlook email body. please suggest.

To highlight all the cells with the name 'Mango' without resorting to JavaScript, you will have to manually add the styling (CSS) you want to your source HTML code.
For example:
<tr>
    <td>ABC302</td>
    <td style="background-color: yellow;">Mango</td>
    <td>5</td>
</tr>

The easiest way to achieve that is to edit your table in any text editor (e.g., NotePad++), and replace <td >Mango</td> with <td style="background-color: yellow;">Mango</td>.

Thank you Mr. Frank, for your response, But I want to highlight the value only if the table has a "Mango" entry. How to specifically achieve that.  I'm getting the table data from the DB query and pass it through a variable ,
rowhtml = """
""" + str(fruitname) + """

What do you mean by 'highlight the value'? Do you want to change the font color of 'Mango' to a different color? Based on your information, it seems the HTML code is already generated dynamically. Wouldn't it be possible to simply add a check, such as str(fruitname) == 'Mango' ? 'yellow' : 'black', in whatever programming language you're using to modify the styling accordingly?

Yes, I would like to highlight with different font color if Mango is listed in the HTML table.

"I'm getting the table data from the DB query and pass it through a variable, ..." - please add this info to your actual question, instead of burying it in a comment below an attempted answer. And mention/ tag what programming language this is supposed to be.
